# vsCode does not accept the $JAVA_HOME UBUNTU 20.04

Tags: visual-studio-code, java-11

I have already found many answers and also tried, unfortunately none worked for me.
I am trying to install Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 20.04. And so far it always went very smoothly. Unfortunately this time not.
My approach was:

1. I installed vscode
2. i installed java
3. i added it to the home(**echo $JAVA_HOME
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64**) and the Path(**echo $PATH
   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin**) variables

$JAVA_HOME, $PATH:
[image]

When it didn't work, I put it in ~/.config/Code/User/settings.json (A **different** path than in **$JAVA_HOME** Because I tried something but that didn't work either)
After all these operations vscode still didn't regest it.

settings.json:
[image]

My question is, why not, did I forget something?

Comment: And if i ask for **java -version** then he give my the right output back
**openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)**

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't regest it"? What do you expect VScode to do and what does it do instead? Have you installed the necessary Java plugins in VScode (primarily [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java))?

Comment: Yes I have installed the addon and I expect that VScode, after setting the $JAVA_HOME variable, will recognize it on the Linux system and then use it for its own terminal. And it doesn't detect that Java is installed (In the Linux own shell it works) nor does VScode detect the path in the **java.home** setting file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but it suddenly works. I installed Java one more time and now it works. Maybe something went wrong with the first java installation.

But thanks to all who took the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the setting `java.home` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`